# Type string[] is not assignable to type Array<string>

Tags: typescript

I have a method in a class

```js
static setSubPermission(permission: boolean, enables: Array<string> = [], disables: Array<string> = [])
```

However, when I call it,

```js
Permission.setSubPermission(true, ['#agent_id'] );
```

I get the following warning: `Type string[] is not assignable to type Array<string>`

When I change the type of `enables` to `string[]` from `Array<string>`, it works fine. But they are more the same thing. What gives?

Here is my `tsconfig.json`

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "module": "esnext",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "lib": [
      "es6",
      "ES2019",
      "ES2020",
      "ESNext",
      "es7",
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable"
    ],
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@js/*": ["public/js/*"],
      "@components/*": ["public/js/components/*"]
    }
  },
  "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types", "./public/js", "./resources"],
  "include": [
    "./public/js/**/*.ts",
    "./resources/**/*.ts",
    "./public/assets/**/*.d.ts",
  ],
  "exclude": ["build", "vendor", "node_modules"]
}
```

Comment: What gives indeed?  Can you provide a [mcve] that behaves the way you’re describing when dropped into a standalone IDE?

Comment: It would probably be helpful to post your `tsconfig.json` file.

Comment: Updated with tsconfig.json

Comment: Still need a MCVE. I put your code into a TS editor but could not reproduce the problem you describe after dummying up some of the missing information. If you want the question to be answerable, post enough code such that, when pasted into https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/, it produces the error you describe

Comment: Sounds like a lint rule. Are you using a framework with built in linting? E.g., Angular and NestJS apps built with their respective CLIs (Command line interfaces) come with built-in stuff you may need to tweak. It is generally good practice to pick one or the other and stay consistent, though I have my reasons to do both, too.

Comment: My bad. It is a lint rule. This lint was in Intellij IDEA.